# How may I Limit decimal to two

Tags: php, paypal, decimal, calculation

Hello everyone and I hope you can help me.

I have `'value' => $amount_to_pay` and I want $amount_to_pay to me multiplied by 0.11 but the output to be limited to only 2 decimals. It is for PayPal.

I used `'value' => $amount_to_pay*0.11` but what comes after the decimal is long and getting an error back from PayPal exp: 589.24*0.11 = 64.8164 I want output to be 64.81

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`round()`](https://php.net/round) to round at N decimals

```
'value' => round($amount_to_pay * 0.11, 2) // 64.82
```

As @PrestonPHX mentionned, that give a round value. If you want to "truncate decimals you could use :

```
'value' => (int)($amount_to_pay * 100) / 100 // 64.81
```

To use a dynamic number of decimals, you could use :

```
$nb = 2; // number of decimals
$exp = pow(10, $nb);
echo (int)($amount_to_pay * $exp) / $exp;
```

Comment: `round()` is likely what should be used here, but this is not a truncate operation

If you round `64.816` to two decimal places, you get 64.82.  Whereas if you truncate, 64.81

Comment: You're right @PrestonPHX , I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes it did help! Thank you!